# Why can't lit-web-components be found in the shadow-dom?

Tags: dom, cypress, google-chrome-devtools, shadow-dom, lit

I'm unable to locate any elements that are located underneath these  `<!--?lit...`-tags. I've got the shadow-dom-option enabled in Chrome's Element Inspector:

[image: Google Chrome Settings]

However, the locator `lion-button-bar[slot="footer"]` should clearly yield a result, but it doesn't. Please note that this is **not** the user-agents' shadow-dom, and all elements **above** the `<!--?lit...`-tags can be found. But it appears as though all elements **below** it don't even exist in the dom:

[image: the DOM as displayed in Chrome's Element inspector]

I wonder if there's a way to access them, specifically using Cypress' `cy.get()`-method. Does anybody have an idea what's going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are dealing with slots, where one element is rendered inside the `<slot>` of a parent element.

The rendering is done by code built into the parent, but you don't see the effect in the DOM when inspecting, so the slots are empty when you look at them (or when Cypress queries them).

From the POV of the test, you can ignore the slots and just query the slot content "template" directly.

For example, this sample page shows parent `<lion-input-datetime>` with a couple of slots. The content of the slots are represented in the DOM as child element, so a simple `.find()` gives you access to them.

```js
cy.visit('https://lion-web.netlify.app/simulator/#?story-file=c62b5352&story-key=extendLionInput&theme=light&platform=web&language=en-US&edge-distance=true');

cy.get('lion-input-datetime')
  .find('label[slot="label"]')
  .should('contain', 'With Date string')

cy.get('lion-input-datetime')
  .find('input[slot="input"]')
  .type('2017-06-01T08:30')
  .should('have.value', '2017-06-01T08:30')
```

**Page**

[image]

**DOM**

[image]

---

You have quite a lot of nesting and I can't get the full picture from what you posted, but hopefully the above will be a guide for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instruct it to specifically traverse into the shadow DOM as regular queries do not.

Looks like `cy.get()` has an option called `includeShadowDom`.
https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get#Arguments

It can also be set as a global config so all your Cypress queries inherit that.
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Global